# Why is the type of "Main.main", "IO ()" and not "IO a"?

Tags: haskell

Why the type of `Main.main` has to be `IO ()` and not `IO String` or `IO Int` or `IO whatever`?

```
main :: IO ([] Char) -- Type error
main = (>>) ((>>=) getLine putStrLn) getLine
```

Comment: I don't get a type error with that code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read `IO a` as "an `IO` computation which produces an `a`" then it begs the question as to what the runtime does with the `a` that `main` produces. It could just drop it. That would require a function like

```
void :: IO a -> IO ()   -- defined more generally in Control.Monad
```

and then give us

```
realMain :: IO ()
realMain = void main
```

There's no particular problem with this except documentation. If I ask you for a value of `IO a` then there remains some uncertainty about what I might choose to do with that `a`. If I ask for a value of `IO ()` then that uncertainty is diminished: I can create values of `()` myself whenever I like, I don't need yours, therefore I must only care about the side effects of running that `IO` computation.

This better matches that actual usage of `main` so for greater type clarity the Haskell runtime might ask for `main :: IO ()`.

This also forces the creator of `main` to be explicit about what they do with any "return values" they create. If I have a `mainish :: IO a` then I need to explicitly `void` it before handing it off to the runtime.

---

That all said, as Sibi points out, GHC actually accepts `main :: IO a` and silently discards the `a`, so the point is a bit moot. See the intro to [Chapter 5](http://www.haskell.org/definition/haskell2010.pdf) of the Haskell Report.

Comment: Come to think of it, wouldn't `IO Int` make sense, with the `Int` used by the runtime as the exit status of the process? Or, I guess `IO Word8` to be POSIX compatible...

Comment: It would, but using [`System.Exit`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/System-Exit.html) is more explicit.

Answer (score 4):

The type of `main` can be `IO a`. This typechecks:

```
main :: IO Int
main = do
  putStrLn "test"
  return 2
```

And then you can execute that yourself:

```
$ ghc -o test test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, test.o )
Linking test ...
$ ./test
test
```

`main` is the function where the program starts executing. So a `main` function with type  `IO a` doesn't make much sense because no other function will be actually making use of the `a` wrapped in `IO`.

Comment: By the way, the reason it's usually written `IO ()` is that it can catch a few bugs. After all, the runtime doesn't *do* anything with the value, so producing one is usually indicative of a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You actually can have `main` be some type `IO T` where `T` isn't `()`.

I think it's a bad thing that this isn't an error though. There is no reason for `main` to be any type other `IO ()` and it can lead to really subtle runtime problems, like

```
main = putStrLn <$> getContents
```

I had a problem like that took me a while to figure out. Of course, this can be prevented by always giving a type signature for all top-level definitions (which everyone should do), but I still feel like there isn't a reason to allow any IO type for `main` other than `IO ()`.

(The problem with the above code is that `main` actually evaluates to an IO action *containing* an IO action, instead of actually being an IO action. I.e., the type is `main :: IO (IO ())`. The correct code would either be `main = join $ putStrLn <$> getContents` or `main = putStrLn =<< getContents`).