# Haskell does not evaluate block

Tags: haskell, http-conduit

I am writing simple sitemap.xml crawler. The code is below. My question is why the code in the end of `main` does not print anything. I suspect it's because haskell's lazyness but don't know how to deal with it here:

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import Text.XML.Light
import Control.Monad.Trans (liftIO)
import Control.Monad
import Data.String.Utils
import Control.Exception

download :: Manager -> Request -> IO (Either HttpException L.ByteString)
download manager req = do
  try $
    fmap responseBody (httpLbs req manager)

downloadUrl :: Manager -> String -> IO (Either HttpException L.ByteString)
downloadUrl manager url = do
  request <- parseUrl url
  download manager request

getPages :: Manager -> [String] -> IO [Either HttpException L.ByteString]
getPages manager urls =
  sequence $ map (downloadUrl manager) urls

main = withManager $ \ manager -> do
  -- I know simpleHttp is bad here
  mapSource <- liftIO $ simpleHttp "http://example.com/sitemap.xml"

  let elements = (parseXMLDoc mapSource) >>= Just . findElements (mapElement "loc")
      Just urls = liftM (map $ (replace "/#!" "?_escaped_fragment_=") . strContent) elements
      mapElement name = QName name (Just "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9") Nothing

  return $
    getPages manager urls >>= \ pages -> do
      print "evaluate me!"
      sequence $ map print pages
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping `getPages` in `return`? It seem unnecessary.

Comment: @arrowdodger Without return I get compilation error: `Couldn't match type ‘IO’
              with ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.ResourceT m’
Expected type: Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.ResourceT
                 m [Either HttpException L.ByteString]
  Actual type: IO [Either HttpException L.ByteString]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into the same problem I describe here, at least as far as having incorrect code that typechecks when it should actually give a type error: [Why is the type of "Main.main", "IO ()" and not "IO a"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458056/why-is-the-type-of-main-main-io-and-not-io-a/22470391#22470391). This is why you should always give `main` the type signature `main :: IO ()` explicitly.

To fix the problem, you will want to replace `return` with `lift` (see http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#v:lift) and replace `sequence $ map ...` with `mapM_`. `mapM_ f` is equivalent to `sequence_ . map f`.

Comment: Thanks, it helped! Now I know that explicit typing and modularize-everywhere is way to win. Here is working version: https://gist.github.com/wishbear/10119638

Answer (score 2):

Substitute your last `return` with `runResourceT` (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/resourcet-1.1.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Resource.html#v:runResourceT). As it's type suggests, it would turn ResourceT into IO action.

Comment: But compiler (and docs) says I need ResourceT there, not IO (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-1.2.0/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#g:4)

Comment: Oh, now i see. You probably need `safeFromIOBase`: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-0.1.1.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Resource.html#v:safeFromIOBase